# Attempting to GREP details of a Java error

Tags: bash, java, scripts, grep

I'm running Ubuntu 11 and I'm having some issues with grep.

I have a shell script (see below) which essentially checks if a certain Java program of mine is running, if not it runs it. That part works out great!

If my Java application throws any kind of exception however I would like to capture that information and email it to myself. How can I go about checking to see if the call to  `java -jar /bin/MyApp.jar` fails? I tried piping it to grep, but that doesn't seem to work.

Below is the full script that I've written:

```
#Check if MyApp.jar is running, if not run it.
if [ $(ps aux | grep 'java' | grep -v grep | wc -l | tr -s "\n") -eq 0 ]
then
echo "PacketCapture Starting...\n"
java -jar /bin/MyApp.jar
echo "PacketCapture Started.\n"
else
echo "PacketCapture already running.\n"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to redirect the output of `stderror` stream to `stdout` stream since exceptions are logged in `stderr` stream. The below snippet can filter the exception strace and prints upto 10 following lines.

```
$ java -jar /bin/MyApp.jar 2>&1 | grep "^Exception" -A10
```

Note:
You can use `jps` command to find the java process for sun JVM. You can also try `pidof` or `pgrep` commands or `grep '[j]ava'`(this one will not list its(grep) process) too.

Comment: This works! Much thanks. Can you however explain 2>&1 does or direct me to some reading on it? I'd hate to just use this and have no idea what it's really doing

Comment: @BOMEz, try this one http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial